# Can I mention a message with its ID

Tags: python, discord.py, report, message, messageid

I have a Discord-Bot (I’m developing with Discord.py) with a report command and the user should pass the ID of the corresponding message (I will don't know in which channel). How can I mention the message with this ID?

I tried <@ID>, but it mentions an unknown user and <#ID>, but it mentions a deleted channel.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can't "mention" a message, all you can do is send a link to it. Instead of trying random formats, read the docs to see which ones exist and what they're for. https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#message-formatting

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can mention a message but you can give a link which can be clicked and will send you to the message.

The format of the link should be:

```
https://discord.com/channels/<GUILD-ID>/<CHANNEL-ID>/<MESSAGE-ID>
```